# How to do separate testing after training / validation in Tensorflow with Batch Normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am having a training script which does training and validation like this:

```
...
print("Initialize training")
logits = utils.inference(images, FLAGS.stacks, True)
v_logits = utils.inference(v_images, FLAGS.stacks, False)

loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'train')
v_loss = utils.get_loss(v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'val')

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_optimizer = utils.pre_training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

validate = utils.validate(v_images, v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.scale)

init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    .....
    # training
    _, loss_list, image_batch, volume_batch, summary_str = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss, images, volumes, summary_train_op])

    .....
    # validation
    _, val_loss_list, summary_str_val, image_input, volume_estimated, volume_ground_truth = sess.run([validate, v_loss, summary_val_op, v_images, v_logits, v_volumes])
```

My inference files creates my model with batch_normaliztion. Therefore I have to create the inference two times, the second time I have to set `reuse=True` for the weights and batch_norm. Additionally, I have to set `is_training=False` for batch_norm. I accomplish this by doing this:

(My inference function calls the model)

```
class model():
    def __init__(self, nb_stack, is_training=True, test=False):
        self.nb_stack = nb_stack
        self.name = name
        self.is_training = is_training
        self.reuse = None if is_training else True

        if test:
            self.is_training = False
            self.reuse = None

     def __call__(self, x):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name, reuse=self.reuse) as scope:
            ....
            norm1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv1, 0.9, epsilon=1e-5, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, scope=sc, reuse=self.reuse, is_training=self.is_training, fused=True)
```

Then after I have finished my training I want to test my finished graph by loading it in another file and perform the test like this:

```
t_image, t_volume = utils.get_test_data(FLAGS.test_file_path)

        #logits = utils.test_inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks)        
        _ = utils.inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks, True)
        logits = utils.inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks, False)

        print("Load meta graph")
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FLAGS.checkpoint_file_path + 'model-' + str(FLAGS.iteration) + '.meta', clear_devices=True)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(t_image.initializer)
            sess.run(t_volume.initializer)

            print("Restore graph")
            saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint_file_path + "model-" + str(FLAGS.iteration))

            print("Process")
            ....  = sess.run([logits, t_image, t_volume])
```

However, when I try to run the test program I always get something like:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value model/preprocessing/beta
>          [[Node: model/preprocessing/beta/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@model/preprocessing/beta"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I do not really know how to set up the graph in the test file.

As you can see I have tried:

```
#logits = utils.test_inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks)  # --> this set test=True in the mode
_ = utils.inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks, True) ## --> These two lines tries to do exactly the same what I have been doing in the training file, but this does not work either
logits = utils.inference(t_image, FLAGS.stacks, False)
```

How can it say it is not initialised even though I call the same interference function?

**EDIT**

When I use:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Then obviously I do not get the error. But that also means that the restore function does not set the variables? Might there be something wrong the two inferences functions? How am I supposed to restore the graph properly when using batch_norm? Cause I have 2 graphs after training.

** EDIT **

When I add:

```
t = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("model/preprocessing/conv1/weights/read:0")

tv = sess.run(t)

print("Load meta graph")
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FLAGS.checkpoint_file_path + 'hourglass-model-' + str(FLAGS.iteration) + '.meta', clear_devices=True)

print("Restore graph")
saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint_file_path + "hourglass-model-" + str(FLAGS.iteration))

 d = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("model/preprocessing/conv1/weights/read:0")

 dv = sess.run(d)

 print("here:")
 print(tv == dv)
```

I get something like this:

```
  [ .... values of true ....]
  ...
  [[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True]]]]
```

Which means that the graph is not restored correctly.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by: haven't seen normalisation a a batch level ever work? Could you be a bit more specific, please? :) @wontonimo

Comment: I am pretty sure that people have been using batch_normalization layers after convolution layers. You just have to treat the differently when training and validation / testing. @wontonimo Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: And I have been doing: validation whilst training, which worked perfectly for me. Testing is basically the same as validation just with the test  dataset. So I do not understand you at all? I am 100% sure this works, if done properly. @wontonimo

Comment: have you heard about the ResNet? That uses skip connections and batch_normalization. @wontonimo

Comment: :) Well, color me educated!  Thanks.

Comment: No problem :). Could you still try to help me? :) It seems like that after I do restore, the weights do not get updated as in they do not get set by restored graph. @wontonimo

Comment: Looking at your last edit, I am not sure this is a good test. At the python level, tensor is a tensor. Can you change this to evaluate the tensor in a session before and after the restore and compare the actual values rather than tensors?

Comment: That code is within the session! Sorry I thought that was obvious and I did not want to bother you with too much code therefore only the important lines @MadWombat

Comment: I understand, but when you do `t == d` you are comparing tensors rather than values and I am not sure that is the same thing. Can you try and do `tv = session.run(t)` and `dv = session.run(d)` and `print(tv == dv)`

Comment: Okay, I have run the test, and the output is an array with values of `true`!  `[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
     True  True  True  True]]]` like this. I have updated my edit as well. @MadWombat

Comment: @MadWombat any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: @thigi I will take another look in a bit

Comment: OK, there are too many edits at this point and I cannot make a clear sense of how your code flows, but one thing I do not see is any line actually saving anything. But since you are getting meta and checkpoint files written, you must be saving somewhere. The next thing that comes to mind is `tf.get_default_graph()`. Looks like you could still be looking at the new, untrained graph rather than the restored graph.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Doesn't make sense really. One thing is confusing to me though. Mostly, weights are initialized randomly from a distribution of some sort, so every time you would create and initialize variables, you would get a different set of values. Yet you seem to get them exactly the same.

Comment: No I do not think so. Every time I initialise them I check them against the new initialised one, therefore it will always be the same. The main problem is, that I actually do not even want to initialise them cause I just want to restore them from the graph. But it is a bit of a problem, since I have 2 inference() methods, one for initialising the training model and one for the initialisation of the validation / test model, which I have to separate since I use batch normalisation. @MadWombat

Comment: Thing is, the restore() should restore variables. If you are getting the same values before and after restore, I see two main possibilities, that your stored values are actually the same as new ones (if your system didn't actually train any weights) or that you are not comparing the right things. Try to check for both possibilities.

Comment: Okay thank you! But is it necessary to use the `tf.train.import_meta_graph` function or shall I rather just use `saver = tf.train.Saver()`? @MadWombat I am a bit confused about all the options I have to call the `restore` method.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but it looks like the purpose of `import_meta_graph` is to preserve all the meta information about graph training, things like global step, batching variables etc. so you can continue your training exactly where you left off. You could just create a new saver object and use restore, you would have to call your inference function first to build a new graph and then load your variables using restore(). I always did that, but then again, my models are just hobby projects.